# How can the 'empty' labelcharts be shown?

Tags: labeling, charts

```
Module[{labels = {"1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", 
"1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", 
"2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", 
"2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016"}, 
data = {1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 7, 12, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2,
 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1}}, 
BarChart[data, 
ChartLabels -> 
Placed[Sort[
Style[#, FontSize -> Scaled[.016]] & /@ labels], {{0.5, 0}, {0.9,
   1}}, Rotate[#, 50 Degree, {Right, Center}] &], 
PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 13}}, 
ImagePadding -> {{40, 10}, {95, 10}}, 
Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, True}}, 
FrameLabel -> {Style["", FontSize -> 5], 
Style["nÂº de publicaciones", FontSize -> 13]}, 
FrameTicks -> {{True, None}, {None, None}}]]
```

I would like to know how can the labels with '0' data be shown. With this code I don't get any label for 1991,1992,... and all other year with '0' data

Thanks in advanced

Comment: I've used '0.0001' instead of 0 and the labels are shown.. But I would like to know if there is a 'better' way to do it

Comment: Based on [your other question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131424/barchart-legend-with-scaled-coordinates), try enclosing `{{0.5, 0}, {0.9, 1}}` in another set of brackets: `{{{0.5, 0}, {0.9, 1}}}`. It would be useful to write in the OP the version you use, as again your code works fine for me under 10.4.1.

Comment: Works fine with version 11.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)

Comment: I use version 9 for Linux 64-bit

Comment: Related Q/A: [Setting `ChartLabels` in a histogram](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66001/125)